# Math.round() is not working in my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

Am very new to php and JavaScript. Am trying to round the value that i get from php and store that value in a JavaScript Variable and display it in a text input.

Below is my code:>

This is my `order_stack.php` file

```
<div class="order Page">
    <h1>Order Entry</h1>    
        <form name="orderEntry" action="process_stack.php" method="post" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for="QUNTY">Quantity: </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input name="quantity" type="text" id="QUNTY">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for="APW">Approx. PCS Weight: </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input name="approxPcsWeight" type="text" id="APW">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
</div>
```

This is my `process_stack.php` file

```
 <?php
        $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
        $ApxPCW = $_POST["approxPcsWeight"];
        $quantity1 = $_REQUEST["quantity"];
        $ApxPCW1 = $_REQUEST["approxPcsWeight"];
        $knittingLT = ($quantity1 * $ApxPCW1) / 200;
    ?>

<fieldset class="new">
    <legend>Entry Tracking Details</legend>
        <p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for ="QTY">Quantity: </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input name="quantity" type="text" readonly="readonly" id ="QTY" value=<?php echo $quantity?>>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for ="APW">Approximate PCS Weight: </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Approx_PCS_weight" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="APW" value=<?php echo $ApxPCW?>>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for = "KLT">Knitting Lead Time: </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Knitting_Lead_time" type="text" id ="KLT" >
                        <script>
                        var data = "<?php echo $knittingLT; ?>";
                        var roundedData = Math.round('data');
                        document.getElementById('KLT').value = roundedData;
                        </script>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </p>
</fieldset>
```

What am doing here is, i multiply both `Quantity` and `Approx. PCS Weight` and divide the obtained value by 200. Then i store the value in `$knittingLT`.

Now in process_stack.php, i want to update the `Knitting Lead Time`(which is a JS variable) by taking `$knittingLT`(which is a php variable) and round up the data and store it in `Knitting Lead Time`.

When i run the files, the `Knitting Lead Time` field is empty.

Is my approach toward this problem is wrong?

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: use `Math.round(data);` instead of `Math.round('data');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are trying to round the string literal 'data'.

Instead of

`var roundedData = Math.round('data');`

write

`var roundedData = Math.round(data);`

Answer (score 2):

You are rounding a string with the word `'data'`.

Instead of `Math.round('data');` use `Math.round(data);`.

---

Also, you are making the PHP outcome a string by putting it between quotes. Although you can use `Math.round` on a string, it is better to make it a number to prevent confusion.

```
20 == '20' // true
20 === '20' // false
```

Try:

`var data = <?php echo $knittingLT; ?>;`

```
<script>
    var data = <?php echo $knittingLT; ?>;
    var roundedData = Math.round(data);
    document.getElementById('KLT').value = roundedData;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `Math.round('data');` to `Math.round(data);`

`Math.round()` expect a number not a string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 var roundedData = Math.round(data); //edited this line 'data' to data
   document.getElementById('KLT').value = roundedData;
```